# Correct SerializeObject method run?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I added json dll in my project and try serialize object:

```
 ProductType itemToEdit = new ProductType("Name");
 string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemToEdit);
```

Error appears:

> An exception of type
>   'System.MissingMethodException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but
>   was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Method not
>   found: 'Boolean
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute.get_IsReference()'.

But project builds correctly.

Comment: what framework is your project targeting? Make sure it's 3.5 or 4

Comment: does it happen with all objects or just ProductType?

Comment: Yes, the project builds correctly because this is a `Runtime` exception.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Installing .NET framework 3.5 SP1 resolved the issue. The DataContractAttribute.IsReference property is only supported in .NET framework 4, 3.5 SP1 and 3.0 SP2

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but I had a similar problem with Newtonsoft.Json when using it with a Windows Phone 7 application.

I was getting 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL when executing JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

I had installed using NuGet and the reference it added was to Newtonsoft.Json.Silverlight.

I changed this to Newtonsoft.Json.WindowsPhone and it resolved the problem.